# How can I reserve a static IP address for my PC on a TPLINK Wireless N ADSL2+ Modem Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, dhcp, ip-address, dhcp-server

I am trying to add a static IP address for my PC. I have tried to search  on Google, and I got on [this page](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/182/) on TP-LINK official website. Unfortunately, the screenshots in the article shows a very different interface from what I have.[enter image description here][2]

The image of the router web interface is on [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfrCX.png). Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: Note - it is not wise to post / upload screenshots of your MAC and your IP addresses (especially your public address) online.

Comment: @Pizza thank you, it never crossed my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address reservation normally ties the computer network card MAC address to a fixed IP address within the router (or server) DHCP range.

If you do not have this capability (lots of routers do not have this capability), determine the DHCP range of the router and then give the computer a Static IP address outside of the DHCP range.

I do this for my desktop computer so it always has the same IP address and so my Sync tool on my laptop computers always works properly.